# Disable the acceleration of my touchpad (libinput)

Tags: touchpad, libinput

I am using libinput, powering my touchpad. I would like to use it without acceleration just like my mouse is (came by default in Manjaro), so I tried to modify my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf file:

```
 Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"
 EndSection
```

But these 3 options just make my pointer really slow and do not turn off the acceleration. (according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392749/mouse-touchpad-acceleration-disabling-not-working and http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-completely-disable-mouse.html)

Comment: I think you need `0` for libinput. Please, check code [in this paragraph](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#with_libinput) and see if that helps *(disclaimer, I'm personally pretty bad in xorg files, and honestly dislike them for being too unclear. If I was you, I'd just execute `xinput set-prop` for the property to disable accel; I can help you with that btw)*

Comment: Thanks for jumping in! So I tried the setup on the arch-wiki for libinput, but it did not change anything. Maybe I could try the set-prop function.
`xinput --set-prop 13 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1           
property 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format` Is where I am stuck right now. !3 is the id according to xinput list

Comment: Ah, I didn't know `xinput` supports alternative command format with `--`. Okay, anyway, a few things: 1. "accel profile" at least for my touchpad indeed doesn't exists, maybe it's specific to mouse ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ either way, you can list properties with `xinput list-props <id>`, and I think you want instead `xinput set-prop 13 "libinput Accel Speed" 0` 2. The number ids *(like the `13`)* are not persistent. Instead you probably want to use actual names. E.g. the command above for my touchpad would be `xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Accel Speed" 0`.

Comment: Ah, and btw: why wouldn't you just disable acceleration in your Desktop Environment settings? It would be far simpler I think: you just open the GUI, and click a checkbox or a slider.

Comment: Yeah but I use i3-wm :D 
Okay I can actually modify my speed with `xinput --set-prop 14 'libinput Accel Speed' 0`. With -1 it gets really slow and with 1 it gets really fast, but the acceleration actually never turns off.

Comment: Hah, cool, same here, I'm using i3wm. Okay, so, did you try the `0` value, is it still accelerated?

Comment: Good taste buddy ;) Yes it seems 0 even was the default value

Comment: Oh, okay, well, this is odd. So, I assume the touchpad has no other properties with "accel" word in it except the `libinput Accel Speed` and `libinput Accel Speed Default` *(please ensure it's the case with `xinput list-props …`)*. Then a way to move forward may be to [report a bug to libinput here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues), the maintainer is pretty active, so you likely to get answer soon. To make sure you provided all relevant information [look at this](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting-bugs.html#reporting-bugs-touchpad).

Comment: I just put up a ticket here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/283 Thanks for the support!